Could not find org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.24180. Required by: project :app > com.connectycube:connectycube-android-sdk-videochat:1.9.2
In my application I am using connectycube videochat sdk but facing an issue, any help will really helpfull
implementation "com.connectycube:connectycube-android-sdk-chat:1.9.2"
implementation "com.connectycube:connectycube-android-sdk-storage:1.9.2"
implementation "com.connectycube:connectycube-android-sdk-pushnotifications:1.9.2"
implementation "com.connectycube:connectycube-android-sdk-videochat:1.9.2"


in app level gradle
maven {
url "https://github.com/ConnectyCube/connectycube-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
}

It sync app properly but while running it shows error
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
Could not find org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.24180.
Required by:
project :app > com.connectycube:connectycube-android-sdk-videochat:1.9.2
 Here is my app level gradle file

// Top-level build file where you can add configurationewTextn options common to all sub-    projects/modules.
    buildscript {
     ext {
    kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
    }
repositories {
google()
jcenter()
maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
maven {
url 'https://jitpack.io'
}
mavenCentral()
// gradlePluginPortal()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
    classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
// gradlePluginPortal()

    maven {
        url 'https://jitpack.io'
    }
    maven { url "https://connectycube.com/maven" }
    maven {
        url "https://github.com/ConnectyCube/connectycube-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
    }

    maven {
        url("$rootDir/..")
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
ext {
chatAdapterVersion = '1.0.2'
}

Checked in other system too below library is causing issue
implemyour textentation "com.connectycube:connectycube-android-sdk-videochat:1.9.2"
If this library is commented out it works
Thanks in advance
I already tried downgrading version of library but no luck.

Have you tried following the Connectycube instructions and using their v2 SDK? The org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.24180 library is no longer available.

I had followed the connectycube instructions and aware of v1 being deprecated, but its still available, and for now I did not want to switch to v2. Thanks.

"for now I did not want to switch to v2" -- you may not have a choice.
